# How to add value to a custom user field when an hook is triggered/fired

Tags: wordpress, field

How do i add value to a custom text field in user profile when an hook is triggered/fired. I have been able to add a custom field called example using the following code

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3><?php _e("Example Section", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="example"><?php _e("Example"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="example" id="example" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'example', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("This field should add YES when to field when a hook is triggered ad empty if hook not triggered."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

And save the input using the following code

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', $_POST['example'] );
}
```

i would like this newly generated custom field to be populated with YES when the user_register hook is triggered (i.e. when a user registers, YES should be added to the field and updated)

So that i can get the YES value and use it to display content dynamically. Something like

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'example', $user->ID ) = 'YES') {
   //Show this page
} else {
   return 'Your are not allowed to view this page';
}
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function add_yes_to_field ( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'winner', 'YES' );
} 
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_yes_to_field');
```

Regarding `get_the_author_meta()`, I don't think you can actually get user meta data with it, because it calls `get_userdata()`. You can use `get_user_meta()` instead.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

Comment: Do i have to declare the $id or its a wordpress global Variable?

Comment: It's a parameter that get's passed to your callback function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register. I had a typo, changed it to $user_id ;)

Comment: Oh! yeah, I understand now, and please how to i use it in the IF statement?`$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( get_user_meta( 'example', $user->ID ) = 'YES') {
   //Show this page
} else {
   return 'Your are not allowed to view this page';
}` ... is this correct?

Comment: `get_user_meta()` takes the user id as first parameter, not the meta key: `if ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'example' ) == 'YES') { //Show this page } else { return 'Your are not allowed to view this page'; }`

Comment: A quick question, is it possible to wrap add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) in an if statement? e.g `if ( add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', 'YES' );
} else {
 update_user_meta( $user_id, 'example', '' );
}`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with that. `add_action()` or `add_filter()` shouldn't be wrapped in conditionals directly because they do not return anything, but you could do something like `if ( is_admin() ) : add_filter( 'something' ); endif;` if you must.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is that when the add_action is triggered it should populate the field with YES, else it should leave the field empty or by default the initial answer handles that? sorry for my lame questions, just want to be sure as i'm adding this to a LIVE site, dont want to break anything...lol

Comment: That's what my code does, basically. Every newly registered user will get the 'YES' meta value in the 'example' user meta field.

Comment: I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ')' ... when i removed the code the site came back on... is there something missing from the code? Php code checker said "Error: There is 1 more opening parenthesis '(' found
This count is unaware if parenthesis are inside of a string

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '{' in your code on line 365 add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) ) {

Comment: Check again, I edited the code. But you still need to understand what you are doing, I'm just trying to give you guidelines. To Copy&Paste code directly onto a live site w/o looking at the code yourself is bad. Use a proper IDE like Netbeans, it's free and it displays many errors in PHP code structures.

Comment: I have updated your code, i had to declare a callback and it worked fine.

Comment: If you use an older version of PHP, you cannot use anonymous functions like I did in my example, which should work just fine on PHP 5.4+

Comment: My server runs on PHP 7.1, not sure why the anonymous functions didn't work but all good now :), Thanks so much